# How to run a single nose test case using Eclipse PyDev?

Tags: pydev, nosetests

I have created a simple test containing two test cases:

```
# test.py

def test_will_pass():
    pass

def test_will_fail():
    assert False
```

In the command-line I can use `nosetests test.py:test_will_fail` to just run the second test case.

The problem is that I have not found a way to create a run configuration in Eclipse PyDev that achieves the same behavior. When I create a *Python unittest* configuration that uses the *Nose test runner*, and pass `test.py:test_will_fail` as argument, it will first run this test case, and then run the entire test, resulting in `test_will_fail` being executed twice.

Is this a bug, or is there any way to create such a run configuration?

Answer (score 4):

Currently PyDev only supports filtering with Ctrl+F9 things inside a class (with the unittest structure).

Please create a feature request at:

https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/

Note: the work to be done in PyDev is guided through votes in the tracker and pull requests.

As a note, the pytest runner already accepts running tests with that structure inside PyDev.